# Ensure a div fits p to one line

Tags: html, css

I have the following, which animates a message. The issue is with the width of #AdvertBox. If I don't set a width, it expands to 100% of the page. If I set an arbitrary width and it's too small, the second message takes up two lines. What should I set it to so it will always be as wide as the second message, maybe with a small amount of padding?

```css
#AdvertBox {
  height: 55px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: 1.75px solid yellow;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-style: italic;
  border-radius: 1px;
  width: 45vw;
}

.scroll-left p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Starting position */
  transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Apply animation to this element */
  animation: scroll-left 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  39% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

.popIn p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Starting position */
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  /* Apply animation to this element */
  animation: popIn 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes popIn {
  /* Move it left */
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  /* Stop It */
  30% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  /* fade out */
  42% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  /* fade out */
  70% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="AdvertBox">
  <div class="scroll-left">
    <p style="position: absolute; z-index: 1 ">
      First Message
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="popIn">
    <p style="position: absolute; z-index: 2 ">
      Second, longer message to drop down
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `white-space: nowrap;` to your `.popIn p` style to prevent the text from wrapping.

I would also recommend removing the `width: 100%;` from the `.popIn p` so that your scrolling animation does end to early. With `width: 100%;` set on the `<p>` it will inherit the width of the parent, which will be shorter then the overflowing text of the `<p>`, making you animation end early.

You might also want to make these same style updates to your other animated `<p>`

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtqLsr6t/3/) for a demo

Comment: This works, but is there a way to set the div to the width of the second p?

Comment: you can set the `min-width: 100%` of the `<p>` so that your centering still works. This will make the div be at least 100% width... but still allow it to get bigger if needed.

Comment: The only way you could make parent div to be the exact same width than the second p without setting a width in CSS is to change it's width once the document is fully loaded with Javascript.